# XPath evaluation always results in empty target node

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I'm trying to create a bind file to change the base type of a property:
[XSD](https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/schema/base/EFL_CTRXBatchSchema.xsd)

My bind file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd
                                    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"
          version="2.1">
<bindings schemaLocation="*">
    <bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='EFilingPriorDocumentNumber']">
        <baseType name="java.lang.String"/>
    </bindings>

</bindings>
</bindings>
```

But XJC always give me the error:

[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xsd:element[@name='EFilingPriorDocumentNumber']" results in empty target node

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Try providing a specific schema location in `schemaLocation`.

Comment: @lexicore The same error happens :/

Comment: Then I'm requesting a [MCVE].